# GSON - Update json files

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to be able to create a new json file, from two existing one.

The first one List of json files this:

```
{
 "Jar_serviceid": "service_v1",
 "Jar_version": "1.0",
 "ServiceId": "srv_v1",
 "ServiceState": "Enable",
 "ServiceVersion": "v1",
 "LicenseRequired": false,
 "ServiceURL": null
 }
```

And the second one is this:

```
{
"Include":[
  {
     "Jar_serviceid":"service_v1",
     "Jar_version":"1.0",
     "ServiceState":"null"
  }
],
"Exclude":"rtm_v2"
}
```

After reading out this both file, I want that the second is updating the first. In this case I want to have something like this at the end:

```
{
 "Jar_serviceid": "service_v1",
 "Jar_version": "1.0",
 "ServiceId": "srv_v1",
 "ServiceState": "null",
 "ServiceVersion": "v1",
 "LicenseRequired": false,
 "ServiceURL": null
 }
```

So every entry from second json file, while edit the first one. Do you have an entry point for me?

I tried something like this:

```
    if (secondconfig != null) {
        if (secondconfig .getInclude() != null) {
            for (ServiceList service : secondconfig.getInclude()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < firstconfig.length; i++) {
                    ServiceList serv = gson.fromJson(firstconfig[i], ServiceList.class);       
                 if(serv.getServiceId().equalsIgnoreCase(service.getJar_serviceid())){
                        // update

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (updatedconfig.getExclude() != null) {
            System.out.println("Execlude: " + updatedconfig.getExclude());
        }
        if (updatedconfig.getVin() != null) {
            System.out.println("VIN: " + updatedconfig.getVin());
        }
    }
```

Maybe there is some better way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to iterate throgh values of second json and make necessary updates to original data, this is how I'd do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson("{\"Jar_serviceid\": \"service_v1\",\"Jar_version\": \"1.0\",\"ServiceId\": \"srv_v1\",\"ServiceState\": \"Enable\",\"ServiceVersion\": \"v1\",\"LicenseRequired\": false,\"ServiceURL\": null}", Map.class);
    Map<String, Object> newValues = gson.fromJson("{\"Include\":[{\"Jar_serviceid\":\"service_v1\",\"Jar_version\":\"1.0\",\"ServiceState\":\"null\"}],\"Exclude\":\"rtm_v2\"}", Map.class);

    if(null != newValues
            && newValues.containsKey("Include") 
            && newValues.get("Include") instanceof List){
        Map<String,Object> firstValue = ((List<Map>) newValues.get("Include")).get(0);
        if(null == data){
            data = new HashMap<>(firstValue);
        }else{
            for(String key : firstValue.keySet()){
                data.put(key, firstValue.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(data));
}
```

We may need to add additional null/type checks depending on nature/format of data we are receiving.

Comment: It works for me! Never thought about using Maps to avoid loops. Now learned something new.  Merci.